# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: eclipse, derby

I have written following code in my application:

```
public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:c:/coopcashier/db/COOP;create=true";

                try {
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from USERS");                        
            
                    while(resultset.next()) {
                        if(resultset.getString(4).toString().equals(txtUsername) && resultset.getString(5).toString().equals(txtPassword)) {
                            homePage home = new homePage();
                            setVisible(false);
                            home.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Username or Password.","Invalid Credentials",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }                   

                    if(conn != null) conn.close();

                    if(statement != null) statement.close();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
```

When I am running this in Eclipse, everything goes well. But when I made the jar file of my project with same code and try to run, it always throw following exception:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

I could not find solution. Please share if anybody resolved this problem.
TIA

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question which tells the class and the line containing `location.toExternalForm()` that fails because `location` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dear. But I resolved the problem myself. In the starting I was thinking it is a problem caused by derby. I used different approach to find out the actual problem. I putted println statements after every line and ran my jar file in cmd and checked the println entries. Then I found that there is no problem with database code. Actual problem was caused by the name of my icon image which I had written as java_logo_icon instead of Java_logo_icon.  This error was exactly on the line number as shown by stack trace. I corrected that and now everything working fine.